# Ubuntu 14.04 and Alienware 14 -> bad sound quality

Tags: sound, alienware

I've managed to make the audio work on my AW 14 laptop(feb-2014), but the sound from the speakers is really bad.  It sounds like my laptop is in a tin can.

**Here is what I noticed:**

- On windows, the sound is perfect, so it's not related to the speakers.
- If I plug in my headset or any headphones, the sound quality is Good
- I've checked and there are no sound effects present. If I connect to bluetooth speakers, sound is good.

Comment: I've been looking around and found this thread : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1302090

Looking at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1302090/comments/30 this comment corrected the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1302090), which is related to the same problem, except about a different driver.

The solution written in [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1302090/comments/30) corrected the problem.  Of course, you need to choose your own Realtek Driver; mine was a different version.

> Thank you so much to everybody for pointing to node 0x1a, work like a
>   charm installing `hdajackretask`, chosing Realtek ALC668, marking show
>   unconnected pins and, find Pin `ID 0x1a` mark override, choose line out
>   (center/LFE) and apply now and that's it enjoy the great sound of
>   Alienware 14